# Eclipse jump to Editor tab shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering if there is any way to have a keyboard shortcut to a tab. Like for example Firefox having <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to go to tab 1 / 2/ 3 etc...

Cheers,

Comment: This would be an attractive feature especially coming from a Linux/GNOME/Firefox environment. I really wish we had this! The Eclipse next/previous tab shortcut seems somewhat inefficient.

Answer (score 20):

You can use <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to the current editor and <kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd> to get a list of open editors. Then you can type a couple of characters to narrow down the list. The currently visible tabs are at the end of the list (use <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Up</kbd> to jump there)

<kbd>Ctrl + PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + PageDown</kbd> select the previous and the next tab.

<kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> goes to the last edit position.

<kbd>Alt + Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt + Right</kbd> go back- and forward through your editing history (like the back button in your browser).

Comment: Hi Aaron, appreciate you are taking the time to write this down but I am more looking for how specifically go to a numbered table....

Comment: I''m not sure this would make sense in the Eclipse UI since the order of the tabs changes all the time. If you need this feature, you probably have to file a bug report along with the request to add the number to the tab's title.

Answer (score 4):

Also, use Alt+PgUp and Alt+PgDown to shift between graphical layout and xml code inside android graphical layout editor for xml files.

Answer (score 0):

for right side move `CTRL+ page Down`

for left side move `CTRL+page Up`

Answer (score 0):

Using `CTRL+F7` to navigate between two currently used views back and forth (kinda `ALT+TAB` in Windows).