# How can I change the view / editor for a file in Eclipse using the keyboard?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Eclipse has a common idiom where when you're editing say an XML file, it may have a "visual" editing view (key/value pairs, tree view, even the Android UI editor), with the option to switch to editing "raw" XML using a tab at the bottom of the window.  I can switch between open documents with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PGUP</kbd>/<kbd>PGDN</kbd>.  Is there a way to switch editors?

I do this a ton when editing Android UIs, and always reaching for the mouse / trackpad is getting really old.

ETA: As another, perhaps more common example, consider editing a pom.xml file with the Maven plugin installed.  You can get multiple "sub-tabs" for project settings, dependencies, reporting, etc., as well as editing the raw XML directly.  I'd like to be able to switch between *those* tabs with a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479062 use Alt + Pg Up and Alt + Pg Down to switch the bottom tabs on the XML editor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an existing (standard) key binding to do that. (Indeed, I'm not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to do).

However, if you go to Window > Preferences > General > Keys, you will see lots of commands that currently have no bound keys.  Select the command that corresponds most closely to whatever you are trying to do and add a custom key binding.

Comment: I've looked at the list of shortcuts, but as you might have guessed I'm not sure exactly what they *call* this class of tabs, so I don't know what to look for.  See my ETA above for possible clarification.